# Can't delete a file at an NTFS partition in Linux

Tags: linux, ntfs, livecd

Can't delete a file at an NTFS partition, even tried this in LiveCD, but at the same partition delete other files not a problem. The file couldn't be deleted is a Windows system file, maybe with special NTFS permissions. So how can I do in the right behavior?

From CLI:

```
sudo rm '/media/.../AppStudio.Uwp.xr.xml' 
rm: cannot remove '/media/.../AppStudio.Uwp.xr.xml': No such file or directory
```

From GUI:

```
Error removing file /media/.../AppStudio.Uwp.xr.xml: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the permission denied error is that the partition is mounted as `ro` (read-only). The reason is mostly that the Windows partition is not properly shutdown and hibernated (you can try running `dmesg` to find the relevant lines)

You can fix this by shutting down Windows properly using `shutdown /s /f /t 0` in the `cmd.exe`.

If that didn't fix the problem I will edit my answer to contain instructions how to manually mount the Windows Partition (in 90%+ of cases shutting down properly fixes it).

Comment: Couldn't he just edit fstab so when its automatically mounted it can be rw instead of ro?

Comment: @Qasim that's a horrible idea, it would possibly corrupt the partition.

Comment: The Windows got deleted too...

Comment: @SirMuffington how would that corrupt it, all it does it change the fileysystem attributes and makes it read, write. that in no way would corrupt it?!!

Comment: @Qasim try it for yourself, it will give you a "NTFS Partition is in a unstable state" error at boot because the partition is inconsistent

Comment: @rospa apparently currently AFAIK the only sure way is for you to boot Windows and shut it down properly, because there are tools like `ntfsfix`, `recover` from `mount.ntfs` in Linux but they get minimal or almost no job done to solve the inconsistency issue. If you're a risk-taker you can go ahead use the recover option, but keep in mind that according to the man page it will clear the Windows Logfile.

Comment: @SirMuffington and if I do it with a ext filesystem? Will the error be the same as NTFS

Comment: @Qasim I am not aware of there being a similar issue upon similar circumstances with ext.